# 2 switch lite switch

Tags: electrical

I have a 2 switch switch, it controls 2 different lights. When one is turned on it sparks and trips the circuit breaker. I disconnected the lite and wire nutted the wires and closed off the outside lite box. I replaced the switch but it still sparks and trips the breaker. I cut the wire going to that lite flush and wire nutted it and used electrical tape. I then put it back in the plastic wall box, reclosed everything the 2nd lite works. Is this safe since the wire I wire nutted is a hot wire?

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Can you provide a wiring diagram? Photo? Anything? We're shooting in the dark here.

Comment: sounds like one of your switches was wired wrong to the 2nd light. with 3 way setups the colors dont always match and many people dont mark the white traveler with black tape. because of this some times with a new switch installed the hot and neutral are connected in 1 position causing the breaker to trip

Answer (score 2):

That is the accepted practice for dead ending a wire. The wire nut and tape. Sounds like you insulated it well enough if everything is working without sparks or tripped breakers now. Just keep your eye on it for a while.